# Slamdata Markdown: Error "There is no binding for the variable :abc" when dropdown have only one option

Tags: mongodb, slamdata

I created a dropdownlist by this query:

```
Month = {!`` SELECT DISTINCT monthCreate FROM `/mongo/ReportDB/TMCMSReportData` where idSubCategory=10 ORDER BY monthCreate``}
```

I get correct values for the dropdownlist. Then I add following query:

```
select count(*) as count,dayCreate from `/mongo/ReportDB/TMCMSReportData` where monthCreate = :Month and idSubCategory=10 group by dayCreate
```

The report work perfect, only if the first query return more than one value. If only one value, it return error

> There is no binding for the variable :Month

I guess that the problem is that Slamdata only trigger "Value Change" event of the markdown, and cannot listen this even when we have only one value. Is it correct? And any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This typically occurs if you create a new query cell that is not linked to the markdown cell.  To link a query cell to the markdown cell, you must use the gray query icon to the left of the markdown cell - not the query cell within the the plus (+) menu.